# Error "URL key for specified store already exists" when enable "Anchor" in category in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: category, catalog, magento2.3.2, url-key, sub-categories

Categories in two different parent with same `url-key`.

First category in the list is saving fine when we update anything in that. But when I am enabling

> Anchor => Yes

In the second category with same `url-key` is not saving and showing an error: `URL key for specified store already exists`. If we any other data in the same category then there is no issue.

How can I fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check `url_rewrite` table with same category Id and remove row.

then you can generate url rewrite again while run indexer.

Comment: No, I have 2 same categories but with different id or different parent.

Comment: how can I set anchor using database?

Comment: you can change url key for category because same url key can not be used.

Comment: I agree but I think it can be same if the category have different parent.